# Where do I complete my departure immigration step? Is it in interior airport or the airport of exiting the country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, connecting-flights

I am an Indian passport holder travelling with below itinerary on a single PNR.

- Bangalore India to New Delhi India Terminal 3 - Air India 1174
- New Delhi India Terminal 3 to New York USA - Air India 101

Can I complete departure immigration and customs in Bangalore airport as layover in New Delhi is for just 1 hour 40 mins?

Comment: It's important to note that wherever you will pass through the exit checkpoint, _it will not be your choice._  Passengers who have cleared exit immigration controls are not mixed with those who have not.

Answer (score 16):

The most common practice globally would be for you to go through immigration departure at the last airport before you leave the country.  However, Air India has a different procedure for some flights.  The full details are here: http://www.airindia.in/Transit-Information.htm

Here are some excerpts relevant to your case.  Your "gateway point" is New Delhi.

> **On a flight that has the number in the range of AI010 – AI399 or AI900 to AI999**
>
> At the origin station (Interior Point), you will be issued with two Boarding Passes one for origin to Gateway Point with "I” indicator printed on it and the second from Gateway Point to Final International Destination with "T” indicator printed on it.
>
> Proceed to complete Immigration and Customs Check formalities at the station of origin (interior station) itself.
>
> At the Gateway Point you will arrive at international terminal and you may proceed directly to International Departure gate through Transit area.
>
> **On a flight that has the number in the range of AI400 – AI899**
>
> At the origin station (Interior Point), you will be issued with two Boarding Passes one for origin to Gateway Point and the second from Gateway Point to Final International Destination.
>
> At the Gateway Point you will arrive at domestic terminal and you may proceed to the international terminal/departure lounge to complete Immigration and Customs Check formalities.

Comment: Of course, the question now remains... What abut flights with numbers outside of either range, like OP's AI1174? I suppose they are in the latter category, but that's just a guess... Also I would be interesting to understand how this is implanted in practice. Are the flights in the first category fully reserved for passengers with an international connection?

Comment: @jcaron, thanks for the comment. I previously didn't notice that 1171 falls outside the ranges.

I just called up Air-India customer care. They told me I should complete departure immigration in Bangalore itself. They gave me some reasons I did not understand (that AI 1174 is not a domestic flight and 1:40 hours is too short for immigration).

Comment: It's not an option for the traveler.  It's simply that some flights work this way and others do not.  The traveler can only choose whether to take a flight that works this way or a different flight that does not (the choice being made at the time of booking the ticket, of course).

Comment: @phoog: Thanks, "option" was a poor choice of word.  I've amended it.